# jQuery .offset value to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#home-btn").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#header").offset().top // Problem
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Can offset actually accept a value of `bottom`?? Since this is one of the links at the bottom of my page and I want to scroll from bottom to top. This brings in the top of the page for a second and then scrolls from bottom to top. How to make a smooth scroll effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say it is a "link", perhaps you just need to prevent the default action of the link:

```
$("#home-btn").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#header").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Otherwise, it seems to work: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58rkntte/)

Comment: This totally worked! Never knew it was that simple! Just give me 5 mins and I'll accept the answer.